# SQL Server Login Failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an ASP application trying to access a database in SQL Server 2008. Here is the connection string in web.config

```
<add name="dbConn" connectionString="data source=testsqlserver; initial catalog=test_db; user id=dbadmin; password=test"/>
```

I followed the instructions for creating a user and login here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

I restarted the sql server and browser services just in case but I am still getting the "Login failed for user 'dbadmin'" error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the server with Management Studio to verify that the username/password are working correctly?

Comment: Your avatar is awesome by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `SQL Server and Windows Authentication` mode selected:

[How to: Change Server Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You made sure the server is allowing SQL logins? Other thing I'd check is that the database has that user and the user has access to the DB.  As @jrummell mentioned, try logging in through Management Studio with the user.  Or post the whole error.